# How to display numbers in different bases under elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

As we know, elisp supports number in different bases, e.g. `#20r1j` equals to 39 in base-10. I want to display `#20r1j` as `#20r1j`. But `(format "%d" #20r1j)` gives me `39`. How to keep the number in its original base?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a format string, you are quite limited in the bases you can display:

> %d means print as number in decimal (%o octal, %x hex).
>   %X is like %x, but uses upper case.

You can use the calc library to manage this for you, however:

```el
(require 'calc-bin)

(let ((calc-number-radix 20))
  (math-format-radix 39))
"1J"

(let ((calc-number-radix 20))
  (math-format-radix #20r1j))
"1J"
```

As with the read syntax you're using, allowed values of `calc-number-radix` run from 2 to 36.